# How to trigger contenteditable mousedown event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I have a somewhat odd setup wherein a table cell is made `contenteditable=true` with a div placed over it to add some border effects without changing the dimensions of any of the cells in the table.  The issue I'm running into is that the div over top of the cell is blocking the `mousedown` call - I already have a handler bound to the div through jQuery (the cell as well, because the div only hovers over the selected cell).

Is it possible to trigger the `mousedown` event on the table cell while passing the event information (mouse position, event.data, etc) from the jQuery handler of the div (positioned over the center the cell with a 2px larger size in each direction - using the CSS "outline" property isn't an option here because some of the cells have different sized borders that throw it off)?

I'm not attempting to call a custom `mousedown` handler in this case for the `contenteditable` cell, but to get the mouse event to propagate to the `contenteditable` cell (for doing things like selection start/end changes).

Edit: I tried this via the follow and it still doesn't work to trigger any of the native `contenteditable` events (moving the selection cursor, setting focus within Chrome [though in Firefox it does set focus if you have already clicked the `contenteditable` div once before]):

```
var x = 10;
var y = 10;
var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window, 1, element.offsetLeft + x, element.offsetY + y, x, y, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/CoryG/SgBy4/

Answer (score 0):

*Idea 1*

If the div you're placing over the cell is not a child of the cell in the DOM then the event won't propagate to the cell.

If you want to pass the event on from the div to the cell you could try jQuery's trigger method.

To focus on the input field after the event is triggered you can add this:

```
// queued and invoked after currently pending event handlers are finished
setTimeout(function(){$('#inputID').focus();}, 0);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/9JNPr/

---

*Idea 2*

Since you need to have the div blocking the editing area during the editing, try adding:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

To your div's css. Mouse events will be ignored completely on by the div.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/9JNPr/4/

Caniuse: http://caniuse.com/pointer-events

Comment: Trigger seems to work for events bound with .bind or similar, but does not trigger the native mousedown function that would move the cursor within a contenteditable field.

Comment: I see what you mean. I've edited in something that'll move the cursor to the input.

Comment: The contenteditable cell already has focus (the div hovering over it cannot have focus, even when clicked) - the issue is moving the cursor.  For instance when you have text within a textbox and click different parts of it the cursor moves, when you mousedown and drag it selects a section of it - those are the "native" events I'm trying to trigger by forwarding mouse position data to the underlying contenteditable cell.